# Is it worth getting a one-week public transportation pass for Rome?

Tags: public-transport, italy, rome

My friend and I are first-time travelers who will be visiting Rome for a week in late September. According to [Rome.info](http://www.rome.info/transportation/tickets/), a week pass could be gotten for 16 Euros. Is it worth buying a week-pass? More specifically:

- Are all the touristy (and some non-touristy) places within walkable distance?
- Can the public transit take us to anywhere that we would want to go in Rome?
- Does the public transit run frequently? Is it safe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [Roma Pass](http://www.romapass.it/) may be worth it for the discounts on tourist attractions, however, my wife and I found that most tourist attractions were not easily accessible from the public transit system (*e.g.*, there are only a handful of metro stations that are close to the historic center of Rome, and they are on the periphery).  [The bus network is extensive](http://www.atac.roma.it/files/doc.asp?r=383), however, it can be difficult to navigate and buses only run on the major boulevards (which excludes many of the smaller streets in old Rome).

If your hotel is well situated and you are only going to be traveling to the major tourist attractions, you may be just as well off walking and taking the occasional taxi.

Answer (score 3):

Living in Rome for 3+ years we often rode the bus and metro. It's true that the metro system is limited (they are building a Line C currently), but the bus system is quite extensive. If you're going to be there for a full week, and you plan on riding the buses and metro, then the Weekly Bus Ticket can be a great buy! See [my blog article on riding buses in Rome](http://www.roninrome.com/%20transportation/bus) for more help on using the bus system. As mentioned in the previous post, Rome is extremely walkable, but depending on WHERE your hotel is located, riding a bus back after a long day "walking the town" could be a blessing. Good Luck!

Comment: 2023-small-update: they are still building a line C, but some stations are open ;)