# What are the popular tourist places to visit while stopping in Rome?

Tags: planning, sightseeing, italy, rome

Me and my girlfriend are stopping in Rome for a week in June.

Currently places that we were thinking of visiting that are popular tourist places are:

- Colloseum, Pantheon, Roman Forum, Palatine Hill
- Baths of Caracalla
- Trevi fountain, Spanish steps
- Vatican (Sistine Chapel and St Peter's Basillica)
- Pompeii (day trip on the train)
- Villa d'Este (in Tivoli)
- Bioparco zoo
- Borghese gardens

Is there any other places that tourists should visit? Maybe there are some places on this list we should try to avoid? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What are your interests? Rome has a lot of sights and to list them all would not be possible.

Comment: There is a related (not duplicate) question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2486/241

Comment: We want to visit places that are rich with history. We're not big fans of art galleries but we aren't ruling them out. Besides that we are fairly open minded about where we visit. Thanks for the related question.

Comment: don't miss the imposing Monument Vittorio Emanuele...you'll probably walk by it on your way from the colosseum to the steps - hard to miss considering the sheer magnitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not miss the [Lux in arcana](http://www.luxinarcana.org/en/) (Light on secrets) exhibit in Vatican. This is a rare opportunity to see some of the most famous documents from the Vatican Secret Archives.

Only from 1st March till September 2012.