# Rome - circumventing ticket lines. Is it even possible?

Tags: tickets, rome, tourist-traps

We are two **non-european adults over the age of 30** spending 4 days between the 10th and the 14th of Aug 2014 in Rome, Italy. Given our nationalities and age, we are probably not eligible for any free entry in the museums and historical sites in Rome.

[What tickets (museum entry and public transport) should we and can we buy online to circumvent lines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/301/2236)? I know from experience that just buying tickets online doesn't help. After that one would need to find a pick-up point for tickets which may not always be near the place of interest or be closed!

Is it worth investing in the 2/4 day [Roma pass](http://www.romapass.it/p.aspx?l=en&tid=2)? Should we be worried about closures of sites on Sundays or Mondays? We are going to stay about 100 meters from the Colosseum, in case this information is pertinent.

**Edit:**

I just realized that asking "is it even possible" can be quite subjective. So I would like add: Is it even possible? If so, what "timing", "advanced purchases" and "circumstances" may we use to avoid long ticket lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that the right answer to your question heavily depends on how many and which museums you are going to visit. Some of them may not even allow to buy tickets online, but others may allow to print the tickets at home.

Roma Pass comes in two versions: 48h and 3-days. It could be a good choice because it allows free direct entry to the first two visited museums in its 3-days version and to the first one in the 48h version. The Colosseum also has a dedicated entry for Roma Pass holders.
For the museum visited thereafter you will get just a discount (some are even free), but no direct access.
Note that the Pass also gives access to public transports (buses, trams, metros).
Of course not every museum in Rome is associated with the Roma Pass; compare the [full list of the places](http://www.romapass.it/p.aspx?l=en&tid=37) and [discounts](http://www.romapass.it/doc/sitiAderentiCostoBiglietti_eng.pdf) to your plans to decide if the Pass is good for you.

Public transports tickets are available at almost any newsagent and at automatic vending machines at any metro station, so you won't need to wait in line to get them.

Each museum has its own opening hours, but as a general rule (widely respected) they are open on Sundays, but closed on Mondays. The Colosseum and the Baths of Caracalla are exceptions and are open also on Mondays.

I hope I have helped. Have a great time in Rome!